# Migrating svn to git with no remote repository?

Tags: git, svn

There are quite a number of questions and answers here that deal with a conversion of an SVN to a git repository. Also online there are quite a few tutorials available ([like this](https://aboullaite.me/migration-from-svn-to-gitlab/) and the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git)). However, none of them deal with the case where you have no remote repository anymore.

I have an old project of mine under svn control. The SVN server I used for that is long gone, but I would like to publish the code with all history on Github. All steps that require access to SVN want to touch my previous SVN server (which is obviously not possible). What can I do to disconnect the server to let `git svn` and the other commands (like the authors collection) work on the local data only?

Comment: What do you have saved locally? If it's just a svn checkout, it doens't have all the history. Recovering parts of it form caches is probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Not having the remote with SVN is problematic ... Not even sure you can retrieve the author of latest changes on the files ...

Comment: Right, I just looked with an svn client at the source folder and it also complains when trying to show the log, since the remote server is not available. Looks like I have just to strip out the `.svn` folders and manually create a git repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git is a *distributed* version control system. This means that when you clone (copy) a git repository, you have another copy of the full repository, including the full history. Even if the original git repo is deleted, your local copy still has the full history.

SVN is a *centralized* version control system. This means that when you checkout a SVN repo, you get the files locally, but not the whole repo. History will not be stored locally.  If the remote SVN repo is deleted or lost, your local workspace (which is itself not an SVN repository) will not contain the history, and your history is lost.

You can delete the .svn directory and store the files in a new Git repo, but history is lost without the original SVN repo.